# CROSS APPLY vs OUTER APPLY speed difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I was using CROSS APPLY to join Users and GeoPhone tables and everything worked fast but now I have Users with NULL values in Phone column. Cross apply skips these rows in final output. So I switched to OUTER APPLY. But it works greatly slower (more than 15 times as slower when total number of rows in output increased just by 1000).

```
SELECT TOP (10000) dbo.Users.Login, dbo.Users.Phone, GeoPhone.Country
FROM  dbo.Users CROSS APPLY
                 (SELECT TOP 1 Country
                 FROM    dbo.GeoPhone
                 WHERE dbo.Users.Phone <= dbo.GeoPhone.[End]) GeoPhone
```

Versus:

```
SELECT TOP (10000) dbo.Users.Login, dbo.Users.Phone, GeoPhone.Country
FROM  dbo.Users OUTER APPLY
                 (SELECT TOP 1 Country
                 FROM    dbo.GeoPhone
                 WHERE dbo.Users.Phone <= dbo.GeoPhone.[End]) GeoPhone
```

I'm trying to understand why. As I see execution plan is different. But theoretically I can't see any computation that may cause such slowdown.

Any ideas?

**MY FINAL SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT TOP (10000) dbo.Users.Login, dbo.Users.Phone, GeoPhone.Country
FROM  dbo.Users CROSS APPLY
                 (SELECT TOP 1 Country
                 FROM    dbo.GeoPhone
                 WHERE ISNULL(dbo.Users.Phone, 0) <= dbo.GeoPhone.[End]) GeoPhone
```

This assigns actual Country for non-null phones and country from first range for null phones (which is "UNKNOWN" for my case already). For some reason `WHERE dbo.Users.Phone <= dbo.GeoPhone.[End] OR dbo.Users.Phone IS NULL` does the same results but greatly slower.

Please feel free to comment this out.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

CROSS APPLY is MSSQL-specific... [Microsoft on APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx)

APPLY causes the right-side query to execute once per result in the left-side query. CROSS  only considers matching rows like INNER JOIN. Using OUTER considers all rows in left-side query. The extra rows hurt.

I recommend you reformulate your right-side query to explicitly accept NULLs instead of using OUTER APPLY.

Comment: Thank you Magicianeer, after your message I tried to reformulate right-side query and found fast solution. I added it to first message.

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
SELECT TOP (10000) dbo.Users.Login, dbo.Users.Phone, GeoPhone.Country
FROM  dbo.Users CROSS APPLY
                 (SELECT TOP 1 Country
                 FROM    dbo.GeoPhone
                 WHERE dbo.Users.Phone <= dbo.GeoPhone.[End]) GeoPhone
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (10000) dbo.Users.Login, dbo.Users.Phone, NULL AS Country
FROM  dbo.Users
WHERE dbo.Users.Phone IS NULL
```

Make sure you have an index on dbo.Users.Phone

Comment: This works fast!! But I found slightly faster solution. I added it to my question.