# CROSS APPLY vs OUTER APPLY when CROSS APPLY matches all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply, outer-apply

Example:

```
UPDATE t
SET Amount = applied.MaxAmount
FROM @test t
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT MAX(t2.Amount) AS MaxAmount
    FROM @test t2
    WHERE t2.Id = t.ForeignId
) AS applied
```

vs

```
UPDATE t
SET Amount = applied.MaxAmount
FROM @test t
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT MAX(t2.Amount) AS MaxAmount
    FROM @test t2
    WHERE t2.Id = t.ForeignId
) AS applied
```

It's my understanding that these two scripts will accomplish the same thing since the MAX() function will always return a result even if that result is NULL. But the OUTER APPLY is much slower than the CROSS APPLY when I apply it to a large dataset.

I would like to know why CROSS APPLY is so much faster. Is it just using a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans?  I could imagine that `outer apply` uses a different plan; I'm surprise there is a large difference (can you quantify it?).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726696/cross-apply-vs-outer-apply-speed-difference

Comment: @GordonLinoff Here are the stats from my actual scenario:
Using OUTER APPLY:
`Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 9218, logical reads 5417660, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'MyTable'. Scan count 4, logical reads 69209, physical reads 2, read-ahead reads 47525, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.`

Comment: Using CROSS APPLY:
`Table 'MyTable'. Scan count 6, logical reads 116178, physical reads 32, read-ahead reads 40690, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.` There are more stats there but they are 0s and I don't have room in this comment.

Comment: @Slideroh That question doesn't actually address the difference in performance at all. Not sure why you posted it.